# Pandas dataframe with key value columns turn keys to new columns from event logs

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like Frame1, how can i take all the items in the key column and transform them into new columns and take the corresponding value and place it like below? I also put the real data set below.

Frame1:

```
name    name2   key    value
matt    face    money  100
matt    face    junk    True
james   face    money   50 
james   face    junk    False
james   face    wife    True
adam    face    money   found
adam    face    wife    False
adam    face    strange yes
```

Expected Output:

```
name      name2    money   junk    wife  strange
matt      face     100     True    NAN   NAN
adam      face     found   False   False yes
james     face     50      False   True  NAN
```

The amount and value of the key column is variable. Thank you for your assistance.

#

Actual data:

```
                        machinename  eventid     entrytype                         source         timegenerated           timewritten username                        message                         action                           keys              vals
0                       mycompname     4688  successaudit  microsoft-windows-security...  3/7/2017 10:38:16 am  3/7/2017 10:38:16 am     NONE  a new process has been cre...  a new process has been cre...                        subject               NaN
1                       mycompname     4688  successaudit  microsoft-windows-security...  3/7/2017 10:38:16 am  3/7/2017 10:38:16 am     NONE  a new process has been cre...  a new process has been cre...                    security id          s-1-5-18
2                       mycompname     4656  failureaudit  microsoft-windows-security...  3/7/2017 10:38:05 am  3/7/2017 10:38:05 am     NONE  a handle to an object was ...  a handle to an object was ...                 account domain         my domain
3                       mycompname     4656  failureaudit  microsoft-windows-security...  3/7/2017 10:38:05 am  3/7/2017 10:38:05 am     NONE  a handle to an object was ...  a handle to an object was ...                       logon id             0x3e7
...                             ...      ...           ...                            ...                   ...                   ...      ...                            ...                            ...                            ...               ...
1381                    mycompname     4688  successaudit  microsoft-windows-security...   3/7/2017 6:47:40 am   3/7/2017 6:47:40 am     NONE  a new process has been cre...  a new process has been cre...         source network address               NaN
1382                    mycompname     4673  successaudit  microsoft-windows-security...   3/7/2017 6:47:40 am   3/7/2017 6:47:40 am     NONE  a privileged service was c...  a privileged service was c...                    source port                 -
1383                    mycompname     4656  failureaudit  microsoft-windows-security...   3/7/2017 6:47:40 am   3/7/2017 6:47:40 am     NONE  a handle to an object was ...  a handle to an object was ...   detailed authentication i...               NaN
1384                    mycompname     4656  failureaudit  microsoft-windows-security...   3/7/2017 6:47:40 am   3/7/2017 6:47:40 am     NONE  a handle to an object was ...  a handle to an object was ...                  logon process            advapi
1385                    mycompname     4656  failureaudit  microsoft-windows-security...   3/7/2017 6:47:40 am   3/7/2017 6:47:40 am     NONE  a handle to an object was ...  a handle to an object was ...         authentication package               NaN
```

#### Update

This is pushing the keys to column names but its not pushing the appropriate values.

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values="vals",index=["MachineName", "EventID","EntryType", "Source", "TimeGenerated", "TimeWritten","UserName", "Message"], columns=['keys'], aggfunc=np.sum)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use [`unstack()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) function.

`Frame1.set_index(['name', 'name2', 'key'])['value'].unstack('key')`

or use [pivot_table()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

`Frame1.pivot_table(columns='key', index=['name','name2'], values='value')`

Comment: Tried this solution, and I think this one is a great solution. Works great in my case. `df.set_index(['name', 'name2', 'key'])['value'].unstack('key').reset_index()`

Comment: can I get what the error is? For my intuition, it may be because you have duplicate rows in your ['name', 'name2', 'key'] columns, like with two same row 'matt, face, money, 100'. Maybe try `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['name', 'name2', 'key']).set_index(['name', 'name2', 'key'])['value'].unstack('key')`?

Comment: yes, that helps. I guess for each ['name', 'name2', 'key'] pair, there may be different actions corresponding to this pair. you have to make ['name', 'name2', 'key'] columns unique so that it can unstack. Try `df['name', 'name2', 'key', 'vals'].drop_duplicates(subset=['name', 'name2', 'key']).set_index(['name', 'name2', 'key'])['vals'].unstack('key')`

Comment: BTW, which columns you want to use as the index? 'name' and 'name2'?

Comment: So IIUC, the index is all the columns expect 'keys' and 'vals' columns

Comment: `Frame1 = Frame1.set_index(Frame1.columns.difference(['vals']))['vals'].unstack('key').reset_index()`